# python concat before

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I'm working on a python project.
I'm doing logs of what happen on my project. For the readability of the logs I need to concatenate strings, but at the beginning and not at the end.

Here is what I want to do :

```
str=''
for(bla in bli):
 str+=bla
str.concatbefore('it works')
```

Finally, I want that str has the following value : `'it works'+'bla[]'`

Is there some way to do so ?

Comment: you should name your string something else as 'str' is a built in function

Comment: I think if you understood what `+=` is short for, you would be able to answer your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: `str` is a very bad variable name, as it is a built-in function.

To the real problem: why not

```
s = ''
for bla in bli:
  s += bla
s = 'it works ' + s
```

Or even better:

```
s = 'it works ' + ''.join(bli)
```

Comment: Thank you, and don't worry for my variables name, it was a sample of what I wanna do, not my code itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
res = 'it works' + res
```

Isn't good enough?

Strings are immutable, so you aren't really changing it in place with `+=`

Answer (score 0):

The conventional way:

```
 s = 'prefix' + s
```

But make sure not to do that in a loop, as it's somewhat slow.